# FIPS 140-2 compliance for Apache and Haproxy on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, openssl, cryptography, haproxy

I have CentOS 7 and Apache and the Haproxy load balancer with SSL support. 
How to make the server compliant to FIPS 140-2?

From [CHAPTER 10. FEDERAL STANDARDS AND REGULATIONS | redhat.com](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security_guide/chap-security_guide-federal_standards_and_regulations)
I got the following instructions:

```
/etc/sysconfig/prelink
PRELINKING=no

# yum install dracut-fips
# dracut -f
fips=1

$ df /boot
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1               495844     53780    416464  12% /boot

boot=/dev/sda1

/etc/ssh/sshd_config
Protocol 2
Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
Macs hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512
```

Is this enough to make my HTTPS services FIPS 140-2 compliant?

Comment: You don't need to do anything to make it FIPS-*compatible*, FIPS algorithms are supported by default. Did you mean FIPS-**compliant**? That's a completely different concept. And it applies to *software* (or more precisely to systems), not to *traffic*. What exactly do you need (**quote** any requirements that you have, don't interpret them, the language is subtle)? What is missing in the page you link to?

Comment: From your perspective, FIPS compliance is a matter of making sure not to use cryptographic software that isn't compliant. Programs that don't use cryptography don't matter. Programs that do (e.g. the HTTPS part of Apache and Haproxy) must be used in FIPS mode.

Comment: Thank you Gilles. Cleared my whole confusion with your second comment statement. `Programs that don't use cryptography don't matter. Programs that do (e.g. the HTTPS part of Apache and Haproxy) must be used in FIPS mode. `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to `SSL/TLS`, `OpenSSL` provides general purpose crypto libraries. In context, `FIPS-mode` merely removes access to all of the algorithms that have not been approved by `NIST`. If in `FIPS mode`, the following command should fail.

```
openssl md5 filename
```

On RedHat system at least, one can also find the status of `FIPS` mode in the `proc` file system.

```
cat /proc/sys/crypto/fips_enabled
```

The result of the command produces `0` (`FIPS` is not enabled.) or `1` (`FIPS` is enabled.).

Is it possible that one may need to regenerate certificates for the Web servers after entering `FIPS` mode? Perhaps.

Is the `FIPS-mode` requirement also a small part of applying a `STIG`?  There exists a very convenient website to view `STIG` requirements. The `RHEL6 STIG` is available at [stigviewer.com](https://stigviewer.com/stig/red_hat_enterprise_linux_6/). Included in the requirements are the commands to apply and verify the settings. It's quite easy to do. The [official source](https://iase.disa.mil/stigs/Pages/a-z.aspx) is somewhat more difficult to use, but a `RHEL7 STIG` does exists there. The `STIGs` from the official sources are produced in XML and expected to be viewed with "STIG Viewer Version 2.7," which can be found in the list of `STIGs`.

**Update**: the RHEL7 STIG is now available at [stigviewer.com](https://stigviewer.com/stig/red_hat_enterprise_linux_7/).

Do the very best you can do, and then let the Information Assurance Officer tell you what more may need to be done. In addition, one could choose to apply the draft version of the `RHEL7 STIG` at the time of installation by choosing a security policy, as illustrated below. This policy does *some* of the "heavy lifting" in `STIG` configuration, but one would still need to verify that all `STIG` settings have been applied.

[image: CentOS7 Security Policy Selection]

There are also other applicable STIGs, one for the Web server and one for the Web application. A database STIG may also apply.